# (_) -> bool not convertible to ()

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

I am having difficulty using a boolean identifier in this section of code.

```
func WorkTypeSearchable() {
    let pathToFile = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("work", ofType: "txt")
    if let path = pathToFile {
        let workString = try! NSString(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        _ = workString.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
        tblSearchResults.reloadData()
    }
}

func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    let searchString = searchController.searchBar.text

    FilteredWorkType = WorkTypeSearchable( { (work) -> Bool in
        let workText: NSString = work

        return (workText.rangeofString(searchString, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch).location) != NSNotFound
    })
    tblSearchResults.reloadData()
}
```

In the line `FilteredWorkType = WorkTypeSearchable( { (work) -> Bool in` I am unable to use it as it crashed the app. But the error it is giving me, I am unable to comprehend.

> (_) -> Bool not convertible to ()

I am guessing this is related to the change from Swift 1 to Swift 2. Can anyone help me correct this error and explain why I would be receiving this error?

I am calling `WorkTypeSearchable` from this section of the code.

```
func WorkTypeSearchable() {

    let pathToFile = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("work", ofType: "txt")

    if let path = pathToFile {

        let workString = try! NSString(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        _ = workString.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")

        tblSearchResults.reloadData()
    }
}
```

`

Comment: How is `WorkTypeSearchable` defined? It seems you are using a parameter in a closure without parameters.

Comment: What is `WorkTypeSearchable`? It seems as if your closure in `WorkTypeSearchable( ...  )` is inferred to be of type `(..) -> Bool`, whereas `WorkTypeSearchable` (initializer?) expects a void/empty tuple argument.

Comment: Are you sure you can assign `work` directly to a `NSString`? That might cause to infer `work` as `NSString` and it could be the root of your issue.

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding code in comments

Comment: From the above, `WorkTypeSearchable` is _a function that expects no arguments_ (which is explained by empty tuple `()`), but you attempt to send it a closure of type `(<type of work>) -> Bool`. Naturally, you'll get a compile time error. Moreover, `WorkTypeSearchable` has no explicit return type, in which case return will be of type `()` (`Void`), in which case you are attempting to assign the _value of the empty tuple_ `()` to `FilteredWorkType` (in case the call to `WorkTypeSearchable` were to be fixed), which I assume is not as intended?

Comment: (Finally, note the convention of using `camelCase` function/property names, and reserve `CamelCase` naming for types. This is the reason why, e.g., your function `WorkTypeSearchable` light up as a type in the syntax highlighting in your question above)

Comment: @dfri it was not intended, I am curious though if based on other questions asked if the NSString declaration might be causing an issue as well?

Comment: Unfortunately there are a lot of errors in this code and it will be very difficult to teach many of the language features to you in this question and answer format. I recommend you seek out some guides on Swift and learn a bit more before attempting something this complex.

Comment: I second Kenneth Bruno:s mark above: you're probably better off starting out with some more basic examples, to get a hang of the syntax of Swift. I believe that applying a day's worth at the [Swift Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html) will be immensely more valuable to you than asking code-specific debugging questions here at SO. Finally (`NSString` question): using a "forced try" is not really runtime-safe, as it'll cause a runtime exception in case the initializer fails, e.g. for invalid file `path`.

Comment: The answer was in front of me the whole time. I was wanting to set `FilteredWorkType = WorkTypeSearch.filter` not `WorkTypeSearchable()`